# fsck (or e2fsck) - Example of difference between -p and -y options

Tags: fsck

Looking at the manual for e2fsck, there are two options that appear very similar:

e2fsck -y (which answers 'yes' to any question answered)

e2fsck -p (which does not ask any questions, and just goes ahead and does whatever it thinks best)

I found this older thread which seems to confirm the above:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132803/what-is-the-difference-between-fsck-options-y-and-p?newreg=1a2c41a3eb4b4086a5d5fb88bc74d813

Whilst I can see the difference, I don't understand the practical impact it might have.

Can someone give me an example of where an Ubuntu system (assume Ubuntu 20.04 LTS if it makes a difference) would do something different if using the -y versus -p options?

The reason for asking is that I have a system that I am trying to bring up a disk on (to copy data off) and I am trying to run:

fsck -pvcf /dev/id

The system is telling me that it cannot run automatically, and needs to be run 'manually' without the -p option.  The problem is that this generated thousands of confirmations (I gave up holding down the 'enter' key and did a Ctrl-C), so I figured I would see if:

e2fsck -yvcf /dev/id

would work, but then wondered what the difference might be, and would there be a downside.

For the avoidance of doubt, I have a ddrescue 'image' of the drive already (I told it to ignore errors and do the best it can), so no real risk of making things any worse - I am mainly just playing around to learn and see what I can achieve with fsck at this point.

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: Using `-y` would yield the same result as using the `-p` and answering `y` to all prompts. With all these issues on this drive, that is the only workable approach you can attempt apart from the better solution of reformatting the partition. Would be interesting to have an example of such confirmation.

Comment: Hi Vanadium,  I agree that -y is the same as answering 'yes' to all prompts.  What I am asking for is an example of where -p would (or could) choose to do something different than -y?  Thanks, Alan.